# Why doesn't the Moonrise appear red when viewed from orbit?

Tags: the-moon, atmospheric-effects

After searching through many videos, I finally found [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQpO1TpcSH0) that shows, **from the perspective of low earth orbit**, the Moon transiting the horizon. It is actually a Moonset, but it shouldn't make a difference.

The Moon does not appear to change its color, neither gold nor red.

This contrasts with my understanding of atmospheric effects. Here on Earth, the Moon does appear more yellow (and when halfway or less above the horizon, even red) during Moonrise. The atmosphere tends to scatter blue light, leaving only yellow and red behind.

So why isn't this happening in the video? From orbit, we should be seeing the Moon through **even more** atmosphere. But I can't detect a trace of red or yellow in the Moon.

Granted it's not the best quality video that it could be. It could be more zoomed in. But it was the **only** video I could find that showed the Moon transiting the horizon from space.

Answer (score 2):

In this video there is blue diffused sunlight present in the atmosphere.  At any point where you might expect blue light to be diffused from the Moon, there is also blue light diffused from the Sun being added back into what you see. To know for sure, you would need to have a recording from night.

The density of air could also be a consideration. The perspective in the video shows the moon from above cloud clover passing below cloud cover. The further the light passes from the Earth's surface doesn't only result in less distance spent in the atmosphere, but also the density of air throughout the entire passage.